# How to show that there is no non trivial solution of second order homogenous equation with $y(0)=y'(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> How to show that there is no non trivial solution of second order homogenous equation with $y(0)=y'(0)=0$?

I had come across above problem .

y=0 is trivial solution of above

If such solution exist say f,g with f satisfies above condition then wronskian become 0. That means solution are linearly depedent .Which is contradication.

Is my argument is correct?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Since there is the trivial solution, how can it be that case that there is no solution?

Comment: You must say how is $$y(x)$$ definied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also argue directly using the theorem of existence and uniqueness of differential equation as

if $p(x),q(x)$ are continous on given domain then given ODE has unique solution passing through (0,0)

But as you mentioned 0 is also solution then by uniqueness it must the trivial solution

Answer (score 3):

About your argument using the Wronskian : I think it is not a good departure because you need beforehand to assume the existence of  2 solutions, whereas you are asked whether there is at least one... Nevertheless, we will use a determinant in the following derivation :

---

Let us assume the contrary, i.e., that a certain homogeneous 2nd order differential equation with constant coefficients :

$$ay''(t)+by'(t)+cy(t)=0            \tag{1}$$

possesses a **non zero** solution $y(t)$ such that $y(0)=y'(0)=0.$

**1) First case :** Let us assume that its characteristic equation $ar^2+br+c=0$ has two **distinct** roots $r_1, r_2$.

Then a solution of (1) is of the form :

$$y(t)=a_1e^{r_1t}+ a_2e^{r_2t} \tag{2}$$

expressing conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$, we get :

$$\begin{cases}a_1&+& a_2&=&0\\a_1r_1&+ &a_2r_2&=&0\end{cases}$$

For a linear homogeneous system (with unknowns $a_1$ and $a_2$) to have a non zero solution, it is necessary that its determinant is $0$.

But this determinant is $\begin{vmatrix}1 & 1\\r_1 & r_2\end{vmatrix}=r_2-r_1$ and we have assumed that $r_1 \neq r_2$. Contradiction.

**2) Second case :** if the characteristic equation has a double root $r$, up to you,  knowing that in this case, you have to replace (2) by :

$$y(t)=a_1e^{rt}+ a_2t e^{rt} \tag{3}$$